# Data tip not working in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-debugging

I have Visual Studio 2017 Community edition, having data tip issues.
Data tip on hover on variables, in case of controllers works, shows data also, but does not work in case of view (i.e, .cshtml - Razor view), I know it should work there too, just can't figure how to make it work.
On hover in view shows the description in tool window, instead of data it holds.
Want to see the data the model or the variable holds in view too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use other windows like the Debug Watch windows to view the real values of the variables.

About this issue that the the Datatip not work for cshtml, I get the same issue as yours, you could report it to the Developer Community site:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Yes, using debug watch, since could not get data tip to work. Thanks by the way.

Comment: @Michael Philips, You are welcome. At least, debug watch window is a workaround for you. If you submit a feedback, you could also share it here, I will also help you vote it. Have a nice day:)